# Cannot use the Yahoo Geoplanet API over HTTPS. What should I do?

Tags: api, geolocation, yahoo

I was using the Yahoo Geoplanet API (https://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/)
which was by far the best solution we could find out there because of mainly two reasons:

- It is a hierarchical API of geolocations (eg. We may search if a city belongs to a country or list the cities of a country etc..)
- We could present the data in the frontend however we wanted. (eg. Google enforces you to display their brand, use their autocomplete, cannot restrict to zones etc..)

However, we moved all our site to HTTPS and we cannot query the http yahoo geoplanet api because it is considered by browsers (good thing) as insecure.

I have been thinking on three possible routes we could take:

1. Hope for someone to tell us "Hey, there is infact an https base url for Yahoo Geoplanet API that for some reason we have not yet found"
2. Hope that someone points us to a Geoplanet alternative that is also hierarchical and that allows us to present the data retrieved however we want and restrict search results to zones.

We don't mind if it is a premium API. This is frustrating and we can't believe there is no solution.

Thank you very much!

Andrés

Comment: Well, for one thing you could “proxy” the requests through your server …

Comment: A note for future reference, Yahoo is retiring the GeoPlanet API see: http://yahoo.tumblr.com/post/120700756894/q2-2015-progress-report-on-our-product